# Ajax CalendarExtender date to multiple TextBox fields

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

At the moment I'm using this:

```
<div class="SidebarRow">    
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox><asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" ImageUrl="~/calendar.png" runat="server" Height="25" Width="25" />   
    <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender" TargetControlID="TextBox1" runat="server" PopupButtonID="ImageButton1" />       
</div>
```

`TargetControlID` is  appending the date to `TextBox1` but I would like to use three textboxes each for day month and year. I was thinking of hiding the `TextBox1` and splitting the date.

Solution: I added before `</body>`

```
<script>
    $('[id$=TextBox1]').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length > 2) {
            date = $(this).val();
            $(this).val(date.substring(0, 2));
            $('[id$=TextBox2]').val(date.substring(5, 3));
            $('[id$=TextBox3]').val(date.substring(6));
        }
    });
</script>
```

The initial date is 19/09/15 and now is separated as it should.

Comment: You can use javascript that extracts the date and assigns the year,month,day to the other textboxes. Can i ask why you want that?

Comment: Well to begin with, I am not familiar with javascript and the reason I want seperate the date is because each textbox will pass as a parameter to a query method.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't pass the arguments to the method manually. `Foo(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day)`. Ot - if you can change the signature of the method - let it accept `DateTime` as parameter.

Comment: The date must pass through a text box because there an option for the user to change the date of month or day or year to 0 and ignore the parameter which is 0 from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On textbox change event using JQuery, Assuming you date format start with `dd/MM/` or `MM/dd`

```
$('[id$=TextBox1]').change( function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 2) {
       date = $(this).val();
       $(this).val(date.substring(0,2));
       $('[id$=TextBox2]').val(date.substring(3,2));
       $('[id$=TextBox3]').val(date.substring(6));
    }
});
```

Comment: I added the script before </body> but it does not work. Only textbox1 holds the day. Also no matter the date I choose I only get the today's day.

Comment: Thanks, it works although I had to change the `substring` parameters a bit. Added solution above.

Comment: Nice to hear the same. We don't have too much time for testing parameter so I thought to give you generel idea :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndDate" runat="server" Width="80" CssClass="InputFormat"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Image ID="imgEndDate" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png" AlternateText="Click to show/hide calendar" />
<cc2:CalendarExtender ID="ceEndDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEndDate" PopupButtonID="imgEndDate" Format="dd-MMM-yyyy"> </cc2:CalendarExtender>
```

It is working fine. When I used textbox as well as click on image.

Comment: How is this different from the poster's code?

Comment: Because used like this Format="dd-MMM-yyyy". So you can manage whatever you want.